# Cannot read property 'textContent' of null

Tags: javascript

The below written code says `cannot read property 'textContent' of null`:

```
<form action="{%url 'Eats_app:pause_button'%}" method="post">
              {% csrf_token %}
              <button class="btn btn-primary " type="submit" value="Pause" id="pausebutton" style="padding-left: 3rem; padding-right: 3rem;" >Pause</button>
              <!-- /* <input class="btn btn-primary " type="submit" value="Pause" id="pausebutton" onclick="toggleTheButton()" style="padding-left: 3rem; padding-right: 3rem;"> */ -->
</form>

document.querySelector('#pausebuttons').textContent.toggle('Pause', 'Resume');
```

Comment: What does your HTML look like?

Comment: `pausebutton` and `pausebuttons` are different.

Answer (score 1):

Your `id` that you are selecting is wrong. Try:
`document.querySelector('#pausebutton').textContent.toggle('Pause', 'Resume');`

To match the `id` of the element:

`<button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Pause" id="pausebutton" style="padding-left: 3rem; padding-right: 3rem;" >Pause</button>`

Answer (score 0):

**Error explanation** to avoid future errors like this.

You are trying to get element `pausebuttons` with query selector but that is **null**.

The Document method `querySelector()` returns the first Element within the document that matches the specified selector, or group of selectors. If no matches are found, null is returned

Here you are getting `null` so no matches found with this selector. May be spelling mistake or something.

Please check it once again in your code.

```
 document.querySelector('#pausebuttons') is null that's why you are getting this error.
```

**Solution:**

You have `id` as `pausebutton` but in selector arguments you are passing `pausebuttons` . Extra **s** at the end.

```
document.querySelector('#pausebutton').textContent.toggle('Pause', 'Resume');
```